# Versioned Model EBEAN ( property version incrementable)

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean

Im looking to make a model versionned, and here is my request

1- Model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "analysis_parameters")
public class Analysis_Parameters extends Model
{

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "analysis_id")
 public Analysis analysis;

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "parameters_id")
 public Parameters parameters;

 @Column(name = "version")
 @Version
 public int version;

 @Column(name = "result")
 public String result;
```

[image]

I would like to auto_increment property VERSION when new parameters are added to the same analysis for example

thank you so much.

Comment: I use the same annotation and after each update it increments the version number: `@Version private int version;`, Do you update when 'adding new parameters?'

Comment: it is not incrementing the property version, however, when inserting, it return an error : duplicate key....